# RubyGem MySQL Binding fails

Tags: ruby

When I executed 'gem install mysql', the error message below appeared.

```
ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/usr/bin/ruby1.8 extconf.rb
extconf.rb:10:in `require': no such file to load -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from extconf.rb:10
```

To workaround this, what should I do?

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems that the ruby-dev package is missing. Try:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. But after the install, the error appeared.ERROR:  Error installing mysql:
 ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.


*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Comment: Looks like there are still some missing dependencies. Check that you have the `build-essential` package installed. After that, check that you have the following packages: `mysql-server` and `libmysqlclient-dev`.

Comment: Before, I would try to run `gem uninstall mysql` to remove the junk produced by previous installation attempts. It may fail, but that's ok as it's not actually installed anyway.

Comment: The build-essential, mysql-server, and libmysqlclient-dev are installed. But the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

1. I added the 'ruby1.8-dev'.

   sudo apt-get install ruby1.8-dev
2. Install mysql.

   sudo gem install mysql
3. It seems to have worked fine.
   But annoying messages appear.

   No definition for next_result

   No definition for field_name

   No definition for field_table

   No definition for field_def

   ...

   Is this OK?

Answer (score 0):

Glad that it finally worked.

Those error messages you're referring to I think they're generated by RDoc output (documentation). Those are just messages stating that there's no documentation available for certain function definitions. Shouldn't be much of a problem.